# What technology allows using your client's bandwidth to distribute continuous events?

Tags: networking, network-programming, bandwidth

Suppose there is a server producing events continuously. That server has clients accessing it via their browsers, which must receive every event produced. If the server sends the events directly to each client, after a number of clients it will certainly exhaust its bandwidth. Are there technologies that allow using your own clients as peers for the distribution of those events?

Comment: It's certainly possible, if each client is willing to install a piece of software. Are those clients on internet servers, or might they be behind internet firewalls of various descriptions? Configuration of the latter (say to home machines) is certainly something to consider.

Comment: Sounds a lot like BitTorrent :)

Comment: I might add they should not have to install any kind of software, just use the browser alone. I'm sure this is possible with flash - I could do it, for example, handling the distribution on my own and sending messages between the clients. I couldn't possibly do that effectively, though - it's too complicated. But I suspect that there should be a solution already - for example, how does twitter distribute it's messages?

Comment: Twitter isn't P2P. You can use Flash for this idea, but only to read from internet servers; as far as I know you can't set up a listener in Flash, which you would need for intermediate clients.

Comment: Hmm I see, that seems bad. If the idea is not possible with Flash I still welcome software-installing solutions!

Answer (score 0):

you sayed your clients are browsers, so the server cannot talk to the clients. but you can ask  the server with AJAX, if there are new events. This technique is called `long polling`, see http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery

Comment: @Eleeist - that would be an interesting idea. Would you expand upon that in a separate answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try http://socket.io/. It allows you to very easily target specific client (browser), specific group of clients (room) or everyone connected and push data to them so that frontend JS can then handle it.

Don't know your backend technology, but it ties in very nicely with node.js.

Comment: But does it use the clients to distribute the messages, or does the server have to send a copy of the message to each one?

Comment: I am not sure how it actually works, but the server sends data over some "channel" defined by you and every client listening to this channel receives the data.